# Delete columns from a square matrix that sum to zero along with corresponding rows

Tags: r, matrix

I have a binary transition matrix.  I want to delete rows associated with columns that sum to zero.  For example, if

```
  A B C D E
A 0 0 0 1 0
B 1 0 0 1 0
C 0 0 1 1 0
D 0 0 1 0 0
E 0 0 1 1 0
```

column B and E sum to zero.  I know how to get rid of the columns like this,

```
> a.adj=a[,!!colSums(a)]
> a.adj
  A C D
A 0 0 1
B 1 0 1
C 0 1 1
D 0 1 0
E 0 1 1
```

but how can I at the same time delete rows B and E to get

```
 A C D
A 0 0 1
C 0 1 1
D 0 1 0
```

Answer (score 1):

If the `rownames` and `colnames` are in the same order

```
indx <- !!colSums(a)
a[indx,indx]
#  A C D
#A 0 0 1
#C 0 1 1
#D 0 1 0
```

Comment: @Daniel McEwen No problem, glad it helped.

Answer (score 1):

Use names to select both columns and rows

```
> ind <- colnames(a[,!!colSums(a)])
> a[ind, ind]
  A C D
A 0 0 1
C 0 1 1
D 0 1 0
```